# Android - "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture"

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am getting an error thrown when I am downloading an image from the internet, and displaying it into an `ImageView`, which is "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture". I know that this means that the image that I am downloading is too large, but I have tried the code:

`final Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1046, 906, true);`

This doesn't work. Are there any other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a smaller texture. Say, 512 by 512 (before scaling). A texture is normally a seamlessy repeating (often square) pattern to be used for tiling a surface.

Comment: Do I use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512, 512, true);`? Becuase I can't set it to 512x512, it's being downloaded from a URL.

Comment: Probably, you have to download a smaller file.